# vb.net data set not working

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dataset, vb.net-2010

I am using two different datasets to populate datagridview my project using visual studio using vb.net. It is windows forms application which is used to display information from the database based on user inputs. Once the information is displayed the user can save the information into a table specifically created to store the report information in order for it to be recalled at a later date. I am now trying to recall this information so have created my dataset in the same way as before and am now trying to invoke a new occurrence of it and this is where the probelm begins. The code is below.

```
Dim dv2 As New System.Data.DataView
dv2 = New System.Data.DataView(DataSet2.Tables(0), "Status <> ''", "",       
DataViewRowState.CurrentRows)
DataTable2TableAdapter.fill(DataSet2.DataTable2, f5.ComboBox2.SelectedValue)
```

I am getting two issues.

1. For `DataSet2.Tables(0)`: `Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference`
2. For `DataTable2TableAdapter`: `’DataTable2TableAdapter’ is not declared.  It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.`

I dont know why this is happening as I have written the same code here as for my previous data set other than changing the SQL statement behind the dataset at set up. Any thoughts would be welcome as I am totally out of ideas. All questions are welcomed.

Thanks

Comment: We need more information here. Namely we could do with seeing where your data adapter is declared and initialized, as well as the same information for DataSet2.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code to fix your error number 1....

```
Dim tablezero as System.Data.DataTable
'
tablezero = DataSet2.Tables(0)
```

The reason your getting the error is because you are trying to access an object (Table(0)) and it is not visible to the code that is trying to access it, if it was SHARED then it would be visible.

So you can resolve it by defining and object instance/reference to it and then accessing that reference, which in this case i have called "tablezero" (or by making table(0) SHARED - usually not the best bet unlessits neccesary - no point in having something accessible to the whole class it is declared in unless absolutelty neccessary)

It is quite possible the second error may dissapear after just fixing above, then again its difficult to tell without your code for Dataset2

Hope it helps.